# How to write this MYSQL Query with count

Tags: mysql

So i have the following table:

```
userid | name | referralcode
```

When users register on the website they put the referralcode of someone else (the referral code is the same number as the userid of someone else)

so im looking for a sql query that will output something like this

20 (this means 20 users have this userid on their referral code) , Gerardo Bastidas,     Valencia

10 , Juan Bastidas,     Valencia

I want to get all info on user. its all located in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT yt1.*, COALESCE(yt2.referral_count, 0)
FROM yourtable yt1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.userid, COUNT(*) AS referral_count
    FROM yourtable t1 INNER JOIN yourtable t2
    ON t1.userid = t2.referralcode
    GROUP BY t1.userid
) yt2
ON yt1.userid = yt2.userid;
```

This query does a self-join and will list every user along with the number of referral codes where his `userid` appears.

Comment: I might explained it wrong, i will fix it in a second, I want to get the count of how many users have the (referral code) of someone else

Comment: This works perfect, is there any way to do a select all? instead of having to choose userid, name ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the work in one query. Replace your table name with 'tbName'
**Tested and working**

```
SELECT countval, userid, email, address
FROM tbName t1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(t2.userid) ASs countval, tt.userid AS xx
    FROM tbName t2
    GROUP BY t2.referralcode
) t3
ON t3.xx = t1.userid
```

**Output:**

```
+-------+-----+------+
| count | uid | name |
+-------+-----+------+
|   3   |  1  | abc  |
|   2   |  2  | xyz  |
|   5   |  3  | kmn  |
+-------+-----+------+
```